# How to handle IController Factory not returning a controller for the request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm using Ninject v. 3 with my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  In my App_Start file, I have the following NinjectControllerFactory that implements the DefaultControllerFactory from MVC; It's pretty standard.

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        ninjectKernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override System.Web.Mvc.IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (controllerType == null) ? null : (System.Web.Mvc.IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }
}
```

The controller factory is then set using the following code:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory(kernel));
```

The problem right now is that if I try accessing a controller *that does not exist*, I get the following error:

**The IControllerFactory '[Name].Web.App_Start.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name [Controller name].**

This error is nice and expected if I pass in a controller that does not exist, but it should be handled more elegantly through say, a 404 page.  How would I do this?  Have a exception catch in the Global.asax file?

Thank You,

Comment: Is there any better answer for this? I'm having the same problem. I could catch the `InvalidOperationException` and then try and inspect the message to see if it originated from Ninject, but that seems awfully hacky.

Comment: A colleague of mine finally found the answer after digging through countless articles online, but I cannot find that bookmarked article unfortunately :/

Comment: Ok, thanks. At least that suggests an answer is out there. If I find it, I'll come back and post it.

Comment: 2013 till now no answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best solution I found was to revert from Asp.net MVC 4 to Asp.net MVC 3, in which the Ninject.Web.MVC assembly completely handles all of this for you.

Though this may be an unacceptable answer for some, it helped solve my issue.